# How to fix - Error during RPC invocation - R3 Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am trying to follow Hello World - Part 1 from Corda tutorials. Where do I need to look at, to understand the error? and what's the solution?

```
   flow start IOUFlow iouValue: 99, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
```

I expect the PartyB to receive iouValue 99 but actually I get

> - [Node thread-1]proxies.ExceptionSerialisingRpcOpsProxy.log - Error during RPC invocation

Comment: check the node logs. The actual exception is currently masked from the client. The node logs will tell you whats actually going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Dan! I went through the logs and resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the parameter only as "PartyB". The syntax would be:

```
flow start IOUFlow iouValue: 99, otherParty: PartyB
```

Comment: Thank you, Austin. But, it was a problem with the placement of  @BelongsToContract and now has got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Place @BelongsToConract in TemplateState before the class declaration. Being a rookie, didn't have the idea of the placement of the annotatioons.

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet? I have my annotation like this: `@BelongsToContract(TestContract.class) public class TestState implements ContractState{ //-- }` But I'm Still getting Issue.